# Не работает scandir

Tags: php

Не работает данный код:

```
$filelist = array();
                            if ($handle = opendir(".")) {
                                while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
                                    if (is_file($entry)) {
                                        $filelist[] = $entry;
                                    }
                                }
                                closedir($handle);
                            }
                            foreach ($filelist as $file)
                            {
                                printf("<td>%s</td><td class='action'><a href='#' class='view'>Загрузить</a><a href='#' class='delete'>Удалить</a></td>", $file);
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал сначала почитать [мануал](http://www.php.su/readdir), а потом лепить...

Вот пример из мануала:

```
<?php
// Обратите внимание, что оператор !== не существовал до версии 4.0.0-RC2

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Дескриптор каталога: $handle\n";
    echo "Файлы:\n";

    /* Именно этот способ чтения элементов каталога является правильным. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        echo "$file\n";
    }

    /* Этот способ НЕВЕРЕН. */
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) { 
        echo "$file\n";
    }

    closedir($handle); 
}
?>
```

В вашем случае его можно поправить на:

```
<?php
$filelist = array();
$dir = __DIR__;
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        if (is_file($file)) $filelist[] = $file;
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
foreach ($filelist as $file)
{
    printf("<td>%s</td><td class='action'><a href='#' class='view'>Загрузить</a><a href='#' class='delete'>Удалить</a></td>", $file);
}
?>
```